# How to select only id by the unique value of other table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table `customers`. How can I select only ids for the distinct values in the email column?

```
+----+------------------+
| Id | Email            |
+----+------------------+
| 1  | sergiy@gmail.com |
| 2  | bob@gmail.com    |
| 3  | anre@gmail.com   |
| 4  | sergiy@gmail.com |
| 5  | antony@gmail.com |
+----+------------------+
```

So the result will be:

```
[1,2,3,5]
```

So far, I've tried:

```
select distinct id, email from customers group by id;
```

Comment: if an email has 2 id's which should should it pick? you can use min(id) or max(id)

Answer (score 3):

`select min(id) from Customers group by email;`